# How do I fade in and out a hidden element using Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to fade in a hidden element, and then fade it back out again using mootools.

I can't just use `$('my_div').fade('toggle')`, because that assumes the element is always visible, whereas my div starts out with `display:none`.

Is there a simple way to combine a fade in/out with a slide in/out or some other way to achieve a nice effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I almost always use Fx.Reveal in Mootools.More:

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Reveal

Very nice fade-in animation, almost no effort on your part.  Fx.Slide might also do the trick, although it tends to be more fiddly.

If you don't want to use Mootools.More, then rolling your own solution with Fx.Morph to change both height and opacity simultaneously could also do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using `display: none` as well.  You can just use this code when you want to fade the element:

To fade in:

```
$('my_div').setStyle('display', 'block');
$('my_div').fade('in');
```

and to fade out:

```
$('my_div').fade('out');
$('my_div').setStyle('display', 'none');
```

Alternatively, you could just setup a class that is called `.hide` with `display: none` set in it, and put that class on your element to start with.  Then it makes the code easier:

```
$('my_div').toggleClass('hide');
$('my_div').fade('toggle');
```

Answer (score 1):

Start out with opacity:0 and display:block. That way you can use fade()

Comment: I don't want to have a huge block of blank space in the middle of my page.

Comment: what do you mean? the blank space is where the element will fade in. If you don't want space, then make the width and height 0 at start and tween that also. figure it out dude...

Comment: See the second sentence is actually an answer that might work.

Answer (score 1):

I do this: I don't hide the element from CSS (*if you have used «display: none» or «visibility: hidden», please remove them before trying what I'm suggesting*). Instead, in «domready», I use «fade('hide')» to hide the element. This way, I can later apply «fade('in')» and «fade('out')» to it.

Answer (score 1):

While you could use More for highlighting an element, using delay or chain is not hard. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLn77n6t/2/

### Method #1:

```
function inout(el){
    el.fade('in').fade.delay(1000, el, 'out');
    }
inout($('fader'));
```

(We pass the element to delay() as otherwise it doesn't know what "this" is.)

### Method #2:

Same as before, but using CSS classes to set the fade properties, and adding and removing the class:

```
<style>
    #fader{opacity:0; transition:opacity 0.5s ease;} 
    #fader.show{opacity:1}
</style>
<script>
    function inout(el){
        el.addClass('show').removeClass.delay(1000, el, 'show');
        }
    inout($('fader'));
</script>
```

### Method #3:

The "correct" method should be to chain the tweens, but I haven't tried. If you need it, post a comment. "Hacky" chaining doesn't work:

```
$('fader').set('tween', {duration:'long', link: 'chain'});    
function inout(){ $('fader').tween('opacity',1).tween('opacity',0); }
```